# Unable to move container initialization as part of a Spring profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

For my integration tests I need an up and running MySQL database. I've decided to set it up through Testcontainers module. Here's how I run it.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class IntegrationTest {

    static MySQLContainer mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.0.33"));

    static {
        mysql.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", mysql::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", mysql::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", mysql::getPassword);
    }
}
```

This works, but I have several integration test classes and it just feels like a bad practice to use the same couple of lines in order to start a container. I'd rather have a class - like a `integration-test` Spring profile - and start it there once. Something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("integration-test")
public class IntegrationTestProfile {

    static MySQLContainer mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.0.33"));

    static {
        mysql.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", mysql::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", mysql::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", mysql::getPassword);
    }
}
```

This, however, fails. The container is launched (I can see that in logs), but the properties are not dynamically overridden and the ones from the `application.properties` are used instead.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an abstract `BaseIntegrationTest` and extend all the tests involving Testcontainers from it: both container and application context will be started once and shared across the tests:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

    static MySQLContainer mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.0.33"));

    static {
        mysql.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", mysql::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", mysql::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", mysql::getPassword);
    }
}

// The following tests share the same container and application context

class SomeRepositoryTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
//...
}

class AnotherRepositoryTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
//...
}
```

Comment: Hi. Are you sure there's no other way? It indeed works: increased my current test suite to run faster by 60sec (not a lot of tests atm), but it surely is not the most elegant solution. Anyway, while it works, I'll have to stick with it. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with a separate configuration class is about using it in multiple tests. Suppose you've got two test classes both importing your config. You'll have two separate application contexts and each starting it's own test container. Most probably this ends in port conflict for both containers use the same port.